# WPF Styling: mouse over change background to ControlTemplate Control

Tags: wpf

I have designed a button within my WPF application, this button layout will be used throughout the application, however the colours will change. There are two parts of the button, the left side has an icon and a background color, then the right side has the text with a different background color.

How can I reference the left sides background color in the Triggers so that when the user mouse over the button it will change to that color?

Side 1: `Name="buttonIcon"`
Side 2: `Name="buttonText"`

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonIcoSmall" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF22252b" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    CornerRadius="5 0 0 5" 
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Background="#434953"
                                    Name="buttonIcon">
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" />
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    CornerRadius="0 5 5 0" 
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Background="#FF22252b"
                                    Name="buttonText" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" 
                                                       FontSize="13"
                                                       Foreground="White"
                                                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </Border>
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="" TargetName="buttonText" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#757b8d" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Right now your IsMouseOver trigger in the ControlTemplate triggers shows a setter for Background with a value of "". When you put a value in there, like "Blue", it isn't working?

Comment: It works yeah, but I need to Bind the Background color of the `buttonIcon` control.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, i assume you have tried adding another trigger in that same ControlTemplate.Triggers section. It would look just like the setter you already have, except the TargetName would be buttonIcon and the Value would be whatever color you choose. Does that not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully I understand the issue correctly. If so, change your `ControlTemplate.Triggers` section to add a Setter for `buttonIcon` as follows:

```
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="" TargetName="buttonText" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" TargetName="buttonIcon" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Since you are handling IsMouseOVer for both parts of the button in the ControlTemplate, you may no longer need your `Style.Triggers` section unless it is providing useful background to the parent layers above the borders.

Comment: Not what i'm after, let me rewrite some of my code so it's a bit more understandable. Sorry.